# draw in a sub view added programmatically?

Tags: ios, drawing, cgcontext

I have a UIScrollView added programmatically to a UIView.
I want to draw few images to the UIScrollView itself.
I know how to draw in the main view using:

[image drawInRect....];

but I just can not understand how to do it inside of a sub view?
i fill that I don't truly understand what is the context and how do i reach it?

thanks for any help.
shani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if any one wants to know -
 the solution is to draw the images to the layer of the UIScrollView.
you can not draw to the view itself without sub classing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to add an image to a uiscrollview which has been added programatically then it is simple.

Add the image to a UIImageView then add that Imageview to the scroll view using addSubview: method.

```
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: hi, thanks but thats not what i want. i want to draw a UIIMage directly to the UIScrollView or any other UIView. when this UIView is inside an other view.